# The next of the week (the structure and meaning)

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, collocation

I have just received an e-mail where a friend of mine (unlike me, a native English speaker) used the phrase "till the next of the week". How common is this? I have been using English as the primary language for study and work for many years but this is the first time I have seen this. 
Usually, I look collocations up either in Oxford Collocations Dictionary or LDOCE/OALD, but this time there's nothing.
The very structure of this phrase implies that the word "next" is used here as a noun, just like some word after it was omitted for brevity or any other reason (for the next [part] of the week). 
Other than that, I don't quite understand the collocation except that it is evidently synonymous with "a new job till next week".

Comment: I've never encountered this phrase.  Sounds like a simple mistake to me.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be a mistake. Sometimes my cursor will move on its own if my mouse drifts, and I wind up typing words in the wrong spot.

Comment: Good to hear that. That was my first impression too, but then I googled and found [this](http://www.express.co.uk/travel/articles/781813/pound-usd-exchange-rate-brexit) and some other links where the phrase is used, which made me start an investigation :) 
Thank you for clarification!

Comment: That link makes no more sense than your original. Both simply appear to be mistakes.